# the output movie is too fast how to control it

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, duration

i have 60 images `000001.jpeg` to `000060.jpeg` now this is my command:

> `"-f image2 -i E:\\REC\\Temp\\%06d.jpeg -r 12 E:\\REC\\Video\\" + label1.Text + ".wmv"`

The output is about 3 second but i expect to get only one minute, so how to set duration for each frame to be one image = one second so 60 image = one minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default frame rate for inputs is 25, so in your example `ffmpeg` is dropping frames to go from 25 to 12 fps (the console output will confirm this).

You can declare just an input frame rate and the output will inherit this same frame rate:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i %06d.jpeg output.wmv
```

Or both an input and an output frame rate:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i %06d.jpeg -r 25 output.wmv
```

This second example is recommended if Windows Media Player has issues with 1 fps content. You will have to experiment to see which example works best for you.

See the [image2 demuxer documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) for more information.